# Is it possible to use Vulkan SDK without manual installation (build from source)?

Tags: c++, cmake, sdk, vulkan

I like to keep dependencies locally.
If my project needs a library the priority is to get it with `FetchContent` instead of asking the user to install it.
This way anyone with a clear system and no knowledge about CMake can use my project by simply following `cmake -S . -B build` and `cmake --build build`.
Also this will keep the global dependencies intact and the user can delete local dependencies at any time by just removing `build` folder.

But it seems that Vulkan SDK cannot be used this way and has to be installed manually.
I couldn't find the sources, only the installers.
This means that I cannot get it as a local dependency with `FetchContent`.

Is this correct? If no and it is possible to fetch the SDK and build it from source, then where I can find the sources with `CMakeLists.txt`?
If yes and it is impossible, then... why? Are they closed-source? Or it is impossible in principle to build this SDK from source for some reason?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can. The SDK is a kit, it gathers many components. You probably need Vulkan-Loader to build vulkan-1, and Vulkan-Headers to use. I don't remember exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the SDK is open source and there are repositories for each of its components.  For example, you can look at this Getting Started [guide](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.3.239.0/linux/getting_started.html) for Linux and find a list of 18 components and their corresponding repositories.